# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PracticeController#show Couldn't find Welcome with 'id'=edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

I have created a CURD operation. Whenever i click on edit, show , delete button it raises the error "Couldn't find Welcome with 'id'=edit" "Couldn't find Welcome with 'id'=show" "Couldn't find Welcome with 'id'=destroy". I have been trying a lot to solve these error but i am getting more and more confused. Please Help!
**Practice.controller**

```html
class PracticeController < ApplicationController
 def index
   @welcome= Welcome.all;
 end
 
 def show
   @welcome = Welcome.find(params[:id])
 end

 def new
  @welcome= Welcome.new;
 end

 def edit
  @welcome = Welcome.find(params[:id]) 
 end

 def create
  @welcome=Welcome.new(params.require(:welcome).permit(:name,:address,:city)) ;
   if @welcome.save
  #redirect_to({ action: 'practices' }, alert: "Record saved")
  redirect_to :root
   else
   render :action=>"new"
 end

 def update
  @welcome = Welcome.find(params[:id])
 
  if @welcome.update(welcome_params)
    redirect_to @welcome
  else
    render 'edit'
   end
 end

 def destroy
  @welcome = Welcome.find(params[:id])
  @welcome.destroy
 
  redirect_to welcome_path
 end
  end
end
```

**

```html
<h3>Please fill the following details</h3>
<hr>
<%= form_with  scope: :welcome , local: true do |f| -%>
<b><i>Name</b></i>:&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp<%= f.text_field :name %> </br></br>
<b><i>Address</b></i>:&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp <%= f.text_area :address %> </br></br>
<b><i>City</b></i>:&nbsp &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <%= f.text_field :city %> </br></br>
<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn-submit" %>

<% end %>

<h2>Listing details</h2>
 
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Address</th>
    <th> City</th>
  </tr>
 
  <% @welcome.each do |welcome| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= welcome.name %></td>
      <td><%= welcome.address %></td>
   <td><%= welcome.city %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', {:controller => "practice", :action => "show", :welcome => welcome.id } %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Edit', {:controller => "practice", :action => "edit", :welcome=> welcome.id } %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Delete', {:controller => "practice", :action => "destroy", :welcome=> welcome.id },
     method: :delete,
     data:{confirm:'Confirm Delete?'}%></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

**
**edit.html.erb**

```html
<h1>Edit Information</h1>
 
<%= form_with(controller: :action=>"edit", local: true) do |form| %>
 
  <p>
    <%= form.label :name %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </p>
 
  <p>
    <%= form.label :address %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :address %>
  </p>

   <p>
 <%=form.label :city %><br>
 <%=form.text_field :city %>
   </p>

  <p>
    <%= form.submit %>
  </p>
 
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below are problematic lines:

In view

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show', {:controller => "practice", :action => "show", :welcome => welcome.id } %></td>
```

In controller

```
def show
         @welcome = Welcome.find(params[:id])
end
```

You are passing the id parameter in `:welcome` in view and trying to access the same in controller by `:id` which is causing the problem. Modify controller as below to fix it.

```
def show
   @welcome = Welcome.find(params[:welcome])
end
```

Comment: Hey thanks Pranav, It worked. Show action is now getting execute. But now there is a new error i am getting in edit action.

Comment: If this answer resolves the issue then please mark it as correct answer. Please ask new question with exact error message you are getting so that I can help you. Thanks!